# How to create 'Read More' in html textarea? I already have javascript function in my .js file, successfully work on calling the 'See More' in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is what my function in the utility.js looks like.

```
function seemoreFunction(dots,more,morebtn,callback) {
  var dots = document.getElementById(dots);
  var moreText = document.getElementById(more);
  var btnText = document.getElementById(morebtn);

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "</br> Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
  callback();
}
```

And below is how I call the function in jqGrid, inline and textarea in mma.js file. (This is working)

```
        loadComplete: function(data){
            data.rows.forEach(function(element){
                if(element.callback_param != null){
                    $("#"+element.callback_param[2]).on('click', function() {
                        seemoreFunction(
                                element.callback_param[0],
                                element.callback_param[1],
                                element.callback_param[2]
                        )
                    });
                }
            });
            if(addmore_jqgrid.more == true){$('#jqGrid2_iladd').click();}
            else{
                $('#jqGrid2').jqGrid ('setSelection', "1");
            }

            addmore_jqgrid.edit = addmore_jqgrid.more = false; //reset
        },
```

I want to call that function again in my html but it is not working. Do I have to add another .getElementById in my assetregister.js file? Below is my html code

```
<div class='input-group'>
    <textarea class="form-control input-sm text-uppercase" name="description" rows="4" cols="155" 
    maxlength="1000" id="description" onload="seemoreFunction()" value="SEE MOREEEEE"></textarea>
</div>
```

Any idea how can I improve my code? Thank you very much

Comment: You can add a button with onclick attribute who will calls same function

Comment: As far as I see you do not pass parameters to this function when calling outside jqgrid, which cause it to not work. Pass parameters when calling it in onload event.